# Prove Equality sin(x+y)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For $\theta \in [0,1]$, show that $sin(x+y)=x+y-\frac 12(x^2+2xy+y^2)sin(\theta(x+y))$

I am not too sure how to attempt this problem, but I think taylor expansion in 2 variables may prove useful. I am not too sure how to apply it though.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think so, that's all the question asks.

Comment: Hint: Use Taylor's formula with error estimated by some middle value.

Answer (score 3):

With $\varphi(u)=\sin u$, then $\varphi(u)=\varphi(0)+\varphi'(0)u+\dfrac{1}{2}\varphi''(\xi_{u})u^{2}$ where $\xi_{u}$ lies in between $u$ and $0$, but then your question should be rephrased as for some $\theta$. And then plug in $u=x+y$.

Comment: one half times the $n^\text{th}$ derivative of phi evaluated at xi sub $u$, times $u$ squared ... try reading that out loud :O